# Font Scaling depending on screen resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using grid layout table for resizing control of my winform application. Which works great.

However font sizes are still same if i set higher resolution.

I set my form autoscalemode=font and tried almost 5-6 solutions that i googled, however it doesn't work.

How can i resize my fontsize depending on the scree resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font("Arial", panel1.Width / 8);
        label1.Font = new Font("Arial", panel1.Height / 4);
    }
```

In this example I used:
TableLayoutPanel fill to form, panel fill to table, label fill to panel

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTtUv.gif)

Comment: it's more fantasy than programming :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. however if i have over 100 labels 'which i have :)' this seems not useful :)

Comment: You could use a loop and enumerate all the labels in the layoutpanel.